# Sync File System command for windows

Tags: windows, filesystems

Is there an equivalent command on windows for the UNIX/Linux `sync` command?  I need to verify all writes caches have been flushed to disk system wide on an as needed basis.  I don't want to disable write caching on the hard drives.

Comment: Note that some hard drives have been known to "lie" and report that writes have completed when they haven't, so the operating system's assurances may not mean much.

Comment: ^ That. It notably applies to USB sticks which have their own internal cache. This is often, but not always, indicated by an LED that keeps flashing for a few seconds after Windows reports it's "safe to remove now"

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There is a similar command available for Windows at http://technet.microsoft.com/sv-se/sysinternals/bb897438(en-us).aspx

Comment: Quite surprised that this tool isn't provided as default at least on windows server.

Comment: @AndersAbel : which is not open source and can't work on ARM.